# Can I use AC voltage for a solenoid lock?

Tags: coil, solenoid

I want to make a very high force solenoid lock. I want to use AC over DC because the most voltage I can get from DC is 12 V (I don't have a power source supply more than 12 V).

So can I use AC to make a solenoid lock?

I will use AC 220 V and 100 ft (50 m) of enamelled wire of 25 gauge to make the coil.

The only thing I fear about is my wire getting extra hot if its resistance is too low.

Comment: A big problem with an AC lock is that if it's designed to be OK for heating when the armature is in contact, when the armature is off, the large reduction in inductance means it will draw a much higher current. Why have you already chosen lengths and gauges of wire, if you haven't calculated currents and heating yet?

Comment: Do you have refernce to check the wire resistance?

Comment: AC solenoids should be designed for use with AC. It is not simply ferromagnetic rod with coil, it is specially mechanical design to reduce magnetic flux fluctuation. Also inductance should be taken in account.

Comment: Use a DC solenoid (with no spring) and a diode.  Pulse the coil (DC) one way, and it "latches."  Flip the diode around and pulse it again, and it "unlatches."  No idle current usage.

Answer (score 0):

Some door openers use solenoid in combination with a latch mechanism. Yes you can use AC just make sure the mechanical design can work with it.